# For a self-adjoint matrix $A$ show that $(zI-A)^{-1}v_j=(z-\lambda_j)^{-1}v_j$

Tags: linear-algebra

For a self-adjoint matrix $A$ show that $(zI-A)^{-1}v_j=(z-\lambda_j)^{-1}v_j$ for the eigenvalues of $A$ and corresponding orthonormal eigenvectors $v_j$ where $1 \leq j \leq n$.

How to start this question? I know that $A$ self-adjoint, so $A=A^*$ and $(zI-A)^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{|zI-A|} \cdot \text{adj}{(zI-A)}$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(zI-A)v_j=(z-\lambda_j)v_j$? This follows from $Av_j=\lambda_jv_j$. Then you only have to prove orthogonality of the eigenvectors $v_j$.

Comment: @Berci I see that by decomposing $zI-A=(z-\lambda_j)I-(A-\lambda_jI)$. But what to do when raising to negative powers?

Comment: Ah, first there was inverse sign only on the left hand side, no?

Comment: @Berci Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the inverse actually exists, you can just use the spectral decomposition of $A$ to get the identity. $A=USU^{T}$, where $S$ is diagonal and $U$ unitary gives $(zI-A)^{-1}=U(zI-S)^{-1}U^{T}$. Since you have the spectral decomposition of the latter matrix you can read the eigenvalues and eigenvectors from it. The eigenvalues are exactly the inverses of $z-\lambda_i$ and the eigenvectors are exactly those from $A$.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: $(zI-A)^{-1}=(zI-USU^{T})^{-1}=(zUIU^{T}-USU^{T})^{-1}=(U(zI-S)U^{T})^{-1}=U(zI-S)^{-1}U^{T}$. For details on the spectral theorem see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Supposed that $B:=zI-A$ is invertible, then $\beta:=z-\lambda_j\ne 0$ (else $v:=v_j\in\ker(B)$), and we have
$$Bv=\beta v\ \implies\ v=B\left(\frac1\beta v\right)\ \implies\ 
B^{-1}v=\frac1\beta v\,.$$